# Error Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php

Intento recuperar del select un L o D, pero hay veces en las veces que me devuelve como undefined porque no encuentra ningún dato. He intentado hacer esto en una función, pero me sigue saltando error :

```
function devolverEstatus($db,$idPhoto,$idUser){
  $sql = "SELECT estatus from estatus where idPhoto = ? and idUser = ? LIMIT 1";
  $consulta = $db->prepare($sql);
  $consulta->execute(array($idPhoto,$idUser));
  $row=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  

  if(is_null($row["estatus"])){
    $estatus='N';
  }else{
    $estatus = $row["estatus"];
  }
  return $estatus;
}
```

Me han sugerido probar con var_dump para ver que me devuelve y hago esto:

```
$estatos = devolverEstatus($db,5,2);
 var_dump($estatos);
```

Y me devuelve string 'N' (length=1)

Comment: Si haces un `var_dump()` de `$estatus` ¿qué obtienes como salida?

Comment: obtengo esto string 'N' (length=1), pero me sigue saliendo el error arriba

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y ahi agrega lo que te pregunté

Comment: Ten en cuenta que null es un valor, no es blanco, por lo que tu comprobación no funciona a no ser que el valor de tabla que devuelves sea = null. Si lo que tienes es un valor vacío usa empty() o $estatus = = ''

Comment: @RafaelM gracias ha funcionado como has dicho, el select efectivamente no me devolvía nada y con empty lo he solucionado. Gracias!!!

Comment: genial vota como resuelta y a otra cosa :)

Comment: Aparte de lo indicado por @RafaelM, puedes ahorrarte todo el bloque `if` poniendo algo así simplemente: `return empty($row["estatus"]) ? 'N' : $row['estatus'];` El ternario hará que se retorne `N` o el valor, encontrado, según el caso.

Comment: O, más simple, usando `fetchColumn()` de este modo: `$estatus=$consulta->fetchColumn(); return $estatus ? $estatus : 'N';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que null es un valor, no es blanco, por lo que tu comprobación no funciona a no ser que el valor de tabla que devuelves sea = null.

Si lo que tienes es un valor vacío usa `empty()` o `$estatus == ''`